# "A legend image format is mandatory" error from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wmts

The following error is received when sending a GetCapabilities Request to WMTS service. I couldn't make a connection between the GetCapabilities call and the error message given. How can I solve this problem?

Note: I found that it worked when I made the same request to the WMS service.

GetCapabilities URL:

```
<server_url>/gwc/service/wmts?Request=GetCapabilities
```

Error Message:

> 400: A legend image format is mandatory

Comment: GetCapabilities using KVP syntax should be `<server_url>/gwc/service/wmts?Request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS&`

Comment: just tested on my local host and it works fine, looks like you broke a layer somewhere in your set up

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.